# xmlHttpRequest nodeValue always null

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to read a simple XML file, but on the one hand always getting null using nodeValue and on the other hand noticed some weird behavior on the child nodes.

First the weird behavior:
This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<productList>
<product>
    <productname>Keilspanner</productname>
    <artikelnummer>m12.123</artikelnummer>
    <productid>2001</productid>
    <objname>keilspanner</objname>
    <length>6</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <height>2.5</height>
</product>
<product>
    <productname>feste Backe</productname>
    <artikelnummer>m12.456</artikelnummer>
    <productid>3001</productid>
    <objname>festeBacke</objname>
    <length>6</length>
    <width>4.4</width>
    <height>2.5</height>
</product>
<product>
    <productname>ClampRail</productname>
    <artikelnummer>123</artikelnummer>
    <productid>1001</productid>
    <objname>clampRail</objname>
    <length>40</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <height>5</height>
</product>
<product/>
</productList>
```

When I print out all child nodes of "product" like that:

```
for(i=0; i<=14; i++){
    console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product")[0].childNodes[i]);
};
```

I get this:

```
loadXML.js:22 #text
loadXML.js:22 <productname>​Keilspanner​</productname>​
loadXML.js:22 #text
loadXML.js:22 <artikelnummer>​m12.123​</artikelnummer>​
loadXML.js:22 #text
loadXML.js:22 <productid>​2001​</productid>​
loadXML.js:22 #text
loadXML.js:22 <objname>​keilspanner​</objname>​
loadXML.js:22 #text
loadXML.js:22 <length>​6​</length>​
loadXML.js:22 #text
loadXML.js:22 <width>​5​</width>​
loadXML.js:22 #text
loadXML.js:22 <height>​2.5​</height>​
loadXML.js:22 #text
```

Every second value is actually a child of my xml file.

Second issue: When i call:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
```

it always returns null.

Here is my complete js:

```
function readXml() {


var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xhttp);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "xml/products.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

}

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    for(i=0; i<=14; i++){
        console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product")[0].childNodes[i]);
    };

    console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue);
}
```

Hope you can help me, I'm new to xml and I'm failing right at the beginning :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every second value is actually a child of my xml file.

Every value is a child node of the first product element.

Every second value is a child *element node*. The others are *text nodes*.

You have white space between the elements. White space is text. Text creates nodes.

> When i call:
>
> ```
> xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
> ```
>
> it always returns null.

That is to be expected. `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product")[0].childNodes[1]` is `<productname>Keilspanner</productname>`, which is an element node.

The [node value of an element is always `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue#Notes).

If you want the text inside it then you have to reach the value of the text node.

```
 xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product")[0].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So you mean the white space in my xml file is actually caused by bad syntax? Or is this common and I just have to use uneven childnumbers to get my values.

Comment: There is nothing bad about the syntax. If you want to get just element nodes, then check the node type in the loop and `continue` if it isn't an element.